# Using "put" command in sftp gives "no such file or directory"

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

I've reviewed this topic:
[How to fix No Such File Or Directory Error message while using sftp Command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810672/how-to-fix-no-such-file-or-directory-error-message-while-using-sftp-command) and some others, however nothing helped me solve this.

Simply put I'm trying to move a file named `blankfile.txt` which is located on my desktop directory on a local machine onto my remote directory in the LAMP server.

I've tried:

```
put Desktop/blankfile.txt  
put blankfile.txt 192.168.x.x:/home/user/Desktop/
put /home/user/Desktop/blankfile.txt
```

(while typing it from the remote working directory)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Find out where you already are: `lpwd`, which files are accessible `lls`. make sure your path is correct.

Comment: well ... lpwd gives me /home/user but not /home/user/Desktop that might be what's causing this.

Comment: so when you are in `/home/user `, `lls` should gives you `Desktop`. is it the case?

Comment: lls gives me all the folders and directories in it. Yes. Including the blankfile.txt

Comment: so your first command `put Desktop/blankfile.txt` should work, unless the file name `blankfile.txt` is not correct. try `lls Desktop/blankfile.txt` to make sure it's there.

Comment: Since I'm sure I'm in the right directory I typed: "put blankfile"  just like that and it started uploading but it spit out "permission denied" need to check file permissions.

Comment: now do a `ls`, to find out where you are. or do a `cd` then use `put` command. it should work.

Comment: ls gives me "index.html" which is the only file in /var/www/html/  that's ok 'coz that's where I'm supposed to be in order to upload files from the local working directory. Permissions of the file seem to be okay. From what I saw on the internet and forum this "no such file or directory" thing is quite common among server users.

Comment: Keep getting "permission denied". I'm in the remote directory as a root. I shouldn't be getting this error, should I ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're not in the correct local path, to find out where is your current directory at your local machine, use: `lpwd`.

If you where in a wrong path then use `lcd` to move into correct path for example:

```
lcd ~/Desktop
```

Know to make sure all your files are in place use: `lls` to get a list of your local files. or even something like this:

```
lls blankfile.txt
```

To make sure it's there. then you can use `put` to start uploading it to remote machine:

```
put blankfile.txt
```

If you've been encountered to any permission error, use `pwd` command to find out where you are at your remote machine.

If you are in a path like `/var` and you did `sftp` with a normal user, it's obvious that you can't upload your files there, in this case you will get an error like:

```
remote open("/root/blankfile.txt"): Permission denied
```

Use `cd` command to change into a directory that you are permitted to write and then use `put` command.

The other permission issue that could happen is your local file permission, which will produce:

```
Couldn't open local file "blankfile.txt" for reading: Permission denied
```

Check your local file permission with `lls -l blankfile.txt`, make sure your current user at your local machine has a right to read that file.

Comment: Will check it all again

Comment: So I made sure the blankfile.txt is on Desktop and typed this as instructed:
lcd ~/Desktop
lls blankfile.txt
ls: cannot access 'blankfile.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Give me a sec to check it myself.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort mate.

Comment: you should use `lls` not `ls` => `lls blankfile.txt`

Comment: And run `lls -l blankfile.txt`, let me know the output of that.

Comment: sftp> lls
    blankfile  
    Downloads
    libinput
    Public
    Videos
    Desktop
    etc
    sftp> pwd
    Remote working directory: /var/www/html
    sftp> put blankfile
    Uploading blankfile to /var/www/html/blankfile
    remote open("/var/www/html/blankfile"): Permission denied

So now we can see it's a permission issue for sure.

The proper formatting is killing me here.

Comment: Seems you don't have the right to write in that path. make sure you are `root`.

Comment: Yeah I'll mark this topic as solved since I strongly believe I'd be able to move that file to the server if it's wasn't for the root authorzation.